# Get only the Max Value of [Count by Date]

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, max, reportbuilder

I have a dataset that gathers all of the orders that were signed in a year.  I need to get the count of Maximum # of orders that were signed in a single day.  I set up a matrix that groups my rows based on date signed and my column in the matrix does the count of orders.

I need to only provide the single date that had the most orders signed.  How do I pull only the max value from a tablix? Or is that not even the right way to start this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than passing a lot of data to SSRS and then trying to apply logic using expressions, I think this would be much easier to do in your dataset query.

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (
        SELECT SignedDate, rCount, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY rCount Desc) as rnk
            FROM (
                        SELECT SignedDate, Count(*) as rCount FROM myTable GROUP BY SignedDate
                ) rc 
    ) a 
    WHERE a.rnk = 1
```

Starting from the inner query we get a count of records by `SignedDate`.

Then we get the `RANK()` of each returned row ordered by descending count.

**Note:** If two `SignedDates` both have the highest number of records, they will both be assigned a rank of 1.

The final outer query just returns anything with a rank of 1.

Your report then only gets the record or records (if more than one date has the same highest count) so you can use a simple table to display them.